# How do I integrate rxjs observables with a plain React Component?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I am new to Rxjs and am trying to learn how to integrate it with a simple React component without any external wrapper/library. I got this working here:

```
const counter = new Subject()

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    number: 0
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    counter.subscribe(
      val => {
        this.setState({ number: this.state.number + val })
      }
    )
  }

  increment = () => {
    counter.next(+1)
  }

  decrement = () => {
    counter.next(-1)

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        Current number {this.state.number} 
        <br /> <br />
        <button onClick={this.increment}>Plus</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>Minus</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/02j7qm2xw

I trouble is that this uses Subjects which is a known anti-pattern according to experts like Ben Lesh:
https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

I tried doing this:

```
var counter = Observable.create(function (observer) {
  // Yield a single value and complete
  observer.next(0);

  // Any cleanup logic might go here
  return function () {
    console.log('disposed');
  }
});

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    number: 0
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    counter.subscribe(
      val => {
        this.setState({ number: this.state.number + val })
      }
    )
  }

  increment = () => {
    counter.next(+1)
  }

  decrement = () => {
    counter.next(-1)

  }


  // - render

}
```

But this fails with the error: `counter.next is not a function`

So How would I use `new Observable()` or `Observable.create()`and use it to `setState` with a plain React component?

Comment: This question could be improved by including at least some of your code, rather than just the link.

Comment: I have now updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `.next()` is an `Observer`'s method, **NOT** `Observables`.

The reason why `Subject` works simply because `Subject` itself is both an `observer` and an `observable`. When you call `subject.next()`, you are simply just updating the `observable` part, and notify all the `observers` about the change.

It can be quite confusing sometimes when comes to `Observable` and `Observers`. To make it simple, think of this way:  `Observable` is someone who produces the data, a.k.a. *data producers*; while `Observer` is someone who consume the data, a.k.a. *data consumer*. In a simple analogy, consumer eats what is produced. For the same token, Observer(consumer) observes(eats) the observable (produced).

In your context (or at least React/Redux paradigm), `Subject` works better. That is because `Subject` has state. It keep tracks of the value over the production of data (job of the `Observable`). Every time the observable (the one inside Subject) changes, or update, any `observers` that subscribes to the `Subject` will get notified. See the pattern similar to redux here? Every time your redux store is updated, your view gets notified (and hence updated). In fact, if you are very used to reactive programming, you can eliminate the use of redux store completely, and fully replace them by `Subject`s and/or `BehaviourSubject`s.

For the post from Ben Lesh, he is merely stating this: Always use an `Observable` if possible, only use `Subject` when it is really needed. In that particular post, he is stating that a click event can just be an `Observable`; using `Subject` will be inappropriate. However, in your context, which is react/redux, using `Subject` is fine - because the `Subject` is used to keep track of the state of the store, and **NOT** the click event handler.

**TLDR:**

1. Use `Subject` if you want to keep track of a state of a variable
2. `.next()` is `Observer`'s method, not `Observable`.

Comment: So using `Subject` here is legit? I guess I've seen most React examples use `Subjects` to create reactive stores. If this is the case then what is Ben Lesh exactly talking about?

Comment: awesome anwer @CozyAzure